# Json data from third party API display in HTML table

Tags: html, json, url, web-scraping, html-table

I have this URL that have json **[LINK](http://108.178.8.199/livecall_service/ratecard.php)**. How can I display this data in HTML table?

**Note:** I don't have access to this file, I just have this URL.

Comment: This is not really a question for SO, since it is not related to programming problems, but asks us to create code for you. Voting to close this

Comment: I need a concept to display this data. Just write some lines that display this data.

Comment: The concept is to parse the data to a JS object and then generate the table.

Comment: Please can you write some lines of code that display data in table.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dmJSON = "--URL--";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Firstcolum+ "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Secondcolumn+ "</td>" + "<td> " + f.Thirdcolumn+ "</td>" +  "<td>" + f.Fourthcolumn+ "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
 });

});
```

Just by using this you can populate the data in table form